# iphone automation testing using uiautomation automation instrument

Tags: ios-ui-automation

i'm using instrument 4.1 and i'm able to run my script but i'm not able to run the same script in instruments 4.2 it is throwing an exception target appears to have died .
Using command line i'm able to load the app but the script is not running.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Script will run only if it has any device / simulator belonging to your upgraded simulator version. If you have upgraded your ios simualator version from 4.X to 5.X, then it will not support and device / simulator belonging to 4.X. Try connecting a device / simulator as per your latest ios simulator version and your script will execute successfully.